# How to do I add ECJ to Gradle ant.importBuild classpath for Liferay portlet project?

Tags: liferay, gradle

I am trying to create a gradle build around a Liferay portlet Ant Build. I am using Gradle for dependency management and managing other non-liferay parts. I need to call some of the Liferay Ant build from Gradle. I am trying to import the Ant build.xml using ant.importBuild. During this process Gradle throws an exception as the Ant build looks for ECJ which is not on the classpath.

I have looked for example Liferay Gradle build's and how to add ECJ to the ant.importBuild classpath which is what is shown below(this still throws the same exception).

```
Task cannot continue because ECJ is not installed.
ECJ was automatically installed. Please rerun your task.
at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:568)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.importResource(ImportTask.java:239)
```

Does anyone have a solution to this? I am new to gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
ant.importBuild 'build.xml' 
configurations { jdt }
dependencies { jdt "org.eclipse.jdt:ecj:3.6.1" }
compileJava {
       doFirst {
                 ClassLoader antClassLoader =org.apache.tools.ant.Project.class.classLoader
                 configurations.jdt.each { File f ->
                                          antClassLoader.addURL(f.toURI().toURL())
                                         }
               }
}
```

Comment: you can add ECJ jar from eclipse also.

Comment: @LuckyBoy I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a work around that doesn't solve the original problem of gradle and ECJ so I will leave the question open.

The workaround calls the system ant. This obviously presumes you have ant installed and on your path.

```
def antExec(target){
  tasks.create(name: "ant$target", type: Exec) {
       executable 'ant'
       args  target
  }
  tasks."ant$target".execute()
}
```

And to call it from a task

```
antExec('deploy')
```

Answer (score 0):

Damien,

To run the ant script for your liferay projects you need to resolve ecj dependency.
You can find ecj*.jar in liferay-tomcat/lib directory copy that jar and place it in ant-home/lib (install directory)
OR

If you are using any IDE from your preference add this jar to your ant runtime to resolve dependency.

Comment: It is running the ant build through a gradle build which imports the Ant build that there is an issue with. The ant build called by itself works